# SpringBoot Security getting Blank Response in postman says 401 unauthorized

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I  have developed REST API's getting correct response in postman and i have added spring security ,code run successful, i can insert the user getting response, but if i perform login getting blank response.I will post the response and code below. Please help me to solve. Thank You

### Controller class :

UserRestController.java

```
package com.jwt.authentication.controller;

import com.jwt.authentication.model.User;

import com.jwt.authentication.model.UserRequest;
import com.jwt.authentication.model.UserResponse;
import com.jwt.authentication.service.IUserService;
import com.jwt.authentication.service.IUserService;
import com.jwt.authentication.util.JwtUtil;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserRestController {
    @Autowired
    private IUserService iUserService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil util;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    //1.Save User in Database
    @PostMapping("/save")
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {

        Integer id = iUserService.saveUser(user);
        String body = "User " + id + " Saved";

        return new ResponseEntity<String>(body, HttpStatus.OK);

//               return ResponseEntity.ok(body);

    }


    //2.Validate User and generate Token(login)
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> loginUser(
            @RequestBody UserRequest request)
    {
        //Validate un/pass with database

        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                request.getUsername(),request.getPassword()));
        String  token = util.generateToken(request.getUsername());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new UserResponse(token,"Success ..!!   Generated by kumar"));
    }
}
```

### Config class :

SecurityConfig.java

```
package com.jwt.authentication.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private InvalidUserAuthEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager()
            throws Exception
    {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception
    {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/save","/user/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

        //TODO: Verify User For 2nd req onwards...
        ;


    }
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
package com.jwt.authentication.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder(){

        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

InvalidUserAuthEntryPoint.java

```
package com.jwt.authentication.config;

//import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class InvalidUserAuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                         HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                         AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,"Unauthorized User");

    }
}
```

Model class

User.java

```
package com.jwt.authentication.model;

//import jakarta.persistence.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.Data;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr_tab")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "roles_tab",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="id")
    )

    @Column(name = "role")
    private Set<String> roles;
}
```

UserRequest.java

```
package com.jwt.authentication.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserRequest {
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

UserResponse.java

```
package com.jwt.authentication.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserResponse {

    private String token;
    private String message;


}
```

**Repository**

UserRepository.java

```
package com.jwt.authentication.repo;

import com.jwt.authentication.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


import java.util.Optional;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Integer> {


Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

### Service

IUserService.java

```
package com.jwt.authentication.service;

import com.jwt.authentication.model.User;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface IUserService {

    Integer saveUser(User user);
    Optional<User> findByUserrname(String username);
}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
package com.jwt.authentication.service.impl;

import com.jwt.authentication.model.User;
import com.jwt.authentication.repo.UserRepository;
import com.jwt.authentication.service.IUserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService, UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder pswEncoder;
    @Override
    public Integer saveUser(User user) {

        //Encode password
        user.setPassword(
                pswEncoder.encode(user.getPassword())) ;


        return userRepository.save(user).getId();

    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> findByUserrname(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
       Optional<User> opt = findByUserrname(username);
       if(opt.isEmpty())
           throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Exist");

       // Read User from DB
        User user=opt.get();
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                username,user.getPassword(),
                user.getRoles().stream()
                        .map(role->new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }




}
```

**Util class**

JwtUtil.java

```
package com.jwt.authentication.util;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Component
public class JwtUtil {

    @Value("${app.secret}")
    private String secret;


    //1. Generate Token

    public String generateToken(String subject){

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(subject)
                .setIssuer("kumar")
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15)))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512,secret.getBytes())
                .compact();
    }

    //2.Read Claims / Read Token Data
    public Claims getClaims(String token)
    {

        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret.getBytes())
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }



    //3.Read Exp Date
    public Date getExpDate(String token){
        return getClaims(token).getExpiration();
    }

    //4.Read Subject/Username

    public String getUsername(String token){
        return getClaims(token).getSubject();
    }


    //5.Validate Exp Date
    public boolean isTokenExp(String token){
        Date  expDate=getExpDate(token);

        return expDate.before(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

    //6.Validate username in token and database,expDate
    public boolean validateToken(String token,String username){
        String tokenUserName =getUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(tokenUserName) && !isTokenExp(token));
    }



}
```

application.properties

```
    #JWT secret
app.secret=kumar

#Connection Properties
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jwt_auth?createDatabaseIfNotExist = true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin

#JPA Properties

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.12</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.jwt.authentication</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot.jwt.authhentication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot.jwt.authhentication</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Jwt Authentication</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Check the logs to see if there are any error messages or exceptions being thrown during the login process.